Android Hilt Plugin exception
I have hilt plugin implemented but Gradle is throwing exception and I cant get it work in this project. Its working fine in my other project where its implemented same way.
libs.versions.toml
[plugins]
blueprint-android-hilt = { id = "blueprint.android.hilt", version = "unspecified" }

build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.blueprint.android.hilt)
}

Exception:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'blueprint.android.hilt', version: 'unspecified']
> Failed to apply plugin 'blueprint.android.hilt'.
   > No value present


Well, as the error says. Somewhere is a value not present that is expected to be set. Use --scan or --stacktrace to gain more insight on where this is coming from.
